# Bootstrap tags input in react app not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I want to use [Bootstrap Tags Input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) in my ReactJS application. I downloaded that component and linked the CSS file and the JS file of the component to index.html file of my react application. Below is the code for the same:

```
  <!-- Bootstrap Tags Input Script -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/Assets/bootstrap-tagsinput-latest/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.css"></link>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/Assets/bootstrap-tagsinput-latest/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Tags Input Script -->
```

Then I simply added `data-role="tagsinput"`to my input element, below is the code for the same:

```
<input
  class="form-control"
  aria-label="Large"
  aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
  placeholder="Search"
  data-role="tagsinput"
  id={style["search-bar-field"]}
 />
```

After doing the above-mentioned steps, I'm still not able to get the bootstrap tags input working. I'm getting the following results (i.e. the input is not being converted to a tag when I click enter):

[image]

Not sure whether it's important or not, but the head element of my index.html file looks like this (I have link and script tags of [Bootstrap Library](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) and [Font Awesome Library](https://fontawesome.com/) in the head element of my index.html file of my ReactJS application):

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
  <!-- Bootstrap Tags Input Script -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/Assets/bootstrap-tagsinput-latest/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.css"></link>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/Assets/bootstrap-tagsinput-latest/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Tags Input Script -->
  <!-- Font Awesome Script -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e5ef6344ab.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Font Awesome Script -->
  <!-- Bootstrap Script -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-wXznGJNEXNG1NFsbm0ugrLFMQPWswR3lds2VeinahP8N0zJw9VWSopbjv2x7WCvX" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.6/dist/umd/popper.js" integrity="sha384-fA23ZRQ3G/J53mElWqVJEGJzU0sTs+SvzG8fXVWP+kJQ1lwFAOkcUOysnlKJC33U" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js" integrity="sha384-CauSuKpEqAFajSpkdjv3z9t8E7RlpJ1UP0lKM/+NdtSarroVKu069AlsRPKkFBz9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign();
    });
  </script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Script -->

  <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
 <title>React App</title>
</head>
```

**NOTE:** I have also installed [bootstrap-tagsinput](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-tagsinput) in my react app from npm but the tags input functionality is still not working.

It would be really great if someone could help me with this or guide me as to where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible if you can create a fiddle or codebox for this ? running code will help to fix the issue.

Comment: bootstrap-tags-input is a jquery plugin, I'm shocked it isn't working in react. Generally speaking, jquery and react are fairly orthogonal in their approaches to UI. Have you checked out [react-boostrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/)